# How can I determine next closest day based on the weekday in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How come the following still displays in GMT? I am trying to get it to display in EST Toronto so I Set the NSTimeZone to localTimeZone

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-dd-MM"];
    NSString *todayDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT]
                                                                                 sinceDate:[NSDate date]]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-dd-MM hh:mm:ss +0000"];

    NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 06:40:00 +0000", todayDateString]]; // 6:40 AM
    NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 07:50:00 +0000", todayDateString]]; // 7:50 AM

    NSLog(@"%@", bus500_monday_To_Friday_T2);
```

Comment: You should take a look at NSCalendar and NSDateComponents first (take a look in the documentation to the  "dateFromComponents:"  method of NSCalendar

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly that you need today's date in your strings other than manually changing hardcoded strings, then you should use this code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-dd-MM"];
NSString *todayDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-dd-MM hh:mm:ss +0000"];
NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 06:40:00 +0000", todayDateString]]; // 6:40 AM
NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 07:50:00 +0000", todayDateString]]; // 7:50 AM
//use above code for all other date variables too.

// rest code would be same
```

After this, you can use date comparisons methods to know which next bus time is nearest to current device time.

Comment: Why would the following code still be showing GMT time? It is 4 hours ahead of the time I want it to display (Toronto EST). I thought by specifying the NSTimeZone localtimeZone it should have taken care of it?

Comment: see edited post.. I have added line to set system time zone.. You can set/change time zone values using 'NSTimeZone'

Comment: It is not working. When I NSLog(@"%@", bus500_monday_To_Friday_T1) it displays 2014-04-29 10:40:00 +0000, which is not right, it should be 6:40. So it is still 4 hours off, I am assuming still GMT since I am EST.

Comment: That's what NSLog does. An NSDate is a point in time, without a time zone.